# Error Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.get_ServerVersion()'.'

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception, database-backups, smo

I want to back up my database using SMO. I have added four (.dll) files to my references; versions of them is 12.0.0.0.

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll  
Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfoExtended.dll  
Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll   
Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll
```

Here is my code:

```
ServerConnection serverconnection = new ServerConnection(new SqlConnection("Data Source = DESKTOP-FUDCNPR; Initial Catalog = DamDB; Integrated Security= True"));
Server server = new Server();

Backup backup = new Backup() { Action = BackupActionType.Database, 
                               Database= "DamDB", };
backup.Devices.AddDevice(@"C:\Data\hamed.bak", DeviceType.File);
backup.Initialize = true;
backup.SqlBackupAsync(server);
```

The error I get is

> System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerVersion Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.get_ServerVersion()'

How to solve this?

Comment: Is there a stack trace along with the error?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by "stack trace " @TheSoftwareJedi